# intval() doesn't seem to work nicely with info from shell (uptime)

Tags: php

I get the values from here

```
$uptime = explode(',', `uptime`);
```

`$uptime[3]` is `load average: 2.26`

However, `intval($uptime[3]);` returns `0`

I thought it may be because of the decimal place, so I tried this as well.

```
$uptime_days = strpos($uptime[0], ' ');
$uptime_days_value = substr($uptime[0], $uptime_days + 9);
echo intval($uptime_days_value);
```

`$uptime_days_value` returns `up 60 days` so `intval()` should return `60` but instead it returns `0`

Comment: by the way, `intval('up 60 days')` returns `0` as well while `intval('60 days')` returns `60` - I think this is what has confused me.

Comment: `intval()` sees the letters and turns them into a zero. Use a regex, or `sscanf` for extracting the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If $uptime[3] is `load average: 2.26` then you will get a 0 return, because `load average` isn't a nmber (integer or real)

```
$uptime[3] = 'load average: 2.26';
echo intval(explode(': ', $uptime[3])[1]);
```

If `$uptime_days_value` is `up 60 days`, intval() will return 0 because `up` is not numeric

```
$uptime_days_value = 'up 60 days';
echo intval(explode(' ', $uptime_days_value)[1]);
```

Comment: I cannot confirm this. I got string `0.04` or `int 1` (of course he should not use the intval function here, but zero is unexpected)

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression

```
<?php
   $string = "load average: 2.26";
   $expression = "/[0-9]+\\.*[0-9]*";

   $matches = array();
   if(preg_match($expression, $string, $matches) != 0) {
      print_r($matches);
   }
 ?>
```

should print if there is a number of the types: # or #.# with any number of digits:

```
 Array
 (
   [0] => "2.26"
 )
```

Note that $matches is passed by reference, so the existing values of $matches is replaced in the function call.

Then, to get the integer or float value:

```
$number = intval($matches[0]);
```